# Photoshop's "Screen" mode in DirectX

Tags: c++, directx, photoshop

Edit: Problem solved! See end of post.

How to implement "Screen" blending mode from Photoshop in DirectX 8?

Info, i've found on this topic (http://www.ziggyware.com/readarticle.php?article_id=228):

> ```
> Result = 1 – (1 – destination) * (1 – source)
> Result = 1 – (1 – source – destination + destination * source)
> Result = 1 – 1 + source + destination – destination * source
> Result = source + destination – destination * source
> Result = destination + source – source * destination
> Result = destination + source * (1 – destination)
> ```
>
> Now that we have the math worked out,
>   we simply have to set the blend modes:
>
> ```
> BlendOperation = Add
> DestinationBlend = One
> SourceBlend = InvDestColor
> ```

I assume DirectX blending states must be:

```
pD3DDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_BLENDOP, D3DBLENDOP_ADD);
pD3DDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_DESTBLEND, D3DBLEND_ONE);
pD3DDevice->SetRenderState(D3DRS_SRCBLEND, D3DBLEND_INVDESTCOLOR);
```

Is it correct? (I have a wrong result)

Sample project: [Link](http://www.fileqube.com/shared/cqktZO1459443) [Mirror](http://rapidshare.com/files/241780033/ScreenBlendTest.zip)

Photoshop result:

http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/7015/photoshopf.jpg

My result in DirectX:

http://img193.imageshack.us/img193/2969/directx.jpg

Problem solving:
formula doesn't consider image alpha, to fix it you need to make image background solid black with 100% opacity

Comment: Problem solved. Forgot to add solution - image on top must be without alpha with solid black background.

Answer (score 2):

Following line is wrong:

```
pD3DDevice->SetTextureStageState(0, D3DTSS_COLOROP, D3DTOP_ADD);
```

Your intention is probably to state alpha blender should do ADD, but the D3DTSS_COLOROP setting does not affect final blender, it sets texture combiner instead. You set it to  add something (result of previous/following stage, or something like that) to the color you sample from the texture, which is wrong. D3DTOP_SELECTARG1 or default D3DTOP_MODULATE should do the job.

What you need to write instead is:

```
pD3DDevice->SetRenderState(D3DBLENDOP, D3DBLENDOP_ADD);
```

Comment: Thank you. Proper render state is D3DRS_BLENDOP in DirectX8. I've fixed my test project but the result is still different with Photoshop. You can see screenshots and sample project in header.

Comment: As the page you have linked to writes, you need to have your image in pre-multiplied alpha representation.

Answer (score 0):

The math seems correct, and the way you set the DirectX functions should work.

My advice is:

1. Use the same images that you are using in Photoshop so you know it's not correctly making pure white (possible).
2. Check that you can do other blending modes and that they generate the correct output.

   - apologies if you have already done both of those.

Comment: Thank you. I've added screenshots to the header